# Use .GetMapAsync instead .getMap method with Google Play Services (Xamarin)

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, google-play-services

An old code works perfectly in this way:

```
LatLng location = new LatLng (myClass.myLocation.Latitude, myClass.myLocation.Longitude);
CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder ();
builder.Target (location);
builder.Zoom (18);
CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build ();
MapsInitializer.Initialize (this);
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition (cameraPosition);
MapFragment googleMap = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment> (Resource.Id.map);
theMap = googleMap.Map;
if (theMap != null) {
    theMap.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
    theMap.MoveCamera (cameraUpdate);
}
```

but now that the `.Map` is obsolete and deprecated, I must to use `.GetMapAsync` in some way:

```
theMap = googleMap.GetMapAsync (IOnMapReadyCallback);
```

But I don't understand how.

There is somebody that can help me?

Comment: I know to do this in java:

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        moveMapAddBounds();

    }
});

but I'm new in C#

Comment: in C# there is no in-place interface implementation ... you have to create class which implements the interface and pass to this function `public class VeryNaiveImpl : IOnMapReadyCallback { public Action<GoogleMap> Callback; public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) { if(Callback != null) Callback(googleMap); } }` then use it like `googleMapFrag.GetMapAsync( new VeryNaiveImpl { Callback = (map)=> { /* map is ready*/ }});`

Comment: Now I've understand thanks, but still I've got an error on the public class: the compiler says than I've not implemented the Android.Gsm.Maps.IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady!!!!

Comment: remeber, size does matter :P

Comment: Serious please.... :D I'm going crazy... there is no documentation on this brand new issue!!!!!!!!!! 

With this code:
  public class waitingMap : IOnMapReadyCallback { 
   public Action<GoogleMap> Callback;
   public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap) { 
    if(Callback != null) Callback(googleMap); 
   } 
  }

I've resolved only one of the three problems but remain two:
1) I does not implement interface member 'Android.Runtime.IJavaObject.Handle.get'
2) I does not implement interface member System.Disposable.Dispose()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69675/discussion-between-blasco73-and-selvin).

Comment: i will not learn you C# ... http://ideone.com/7PoSdp

Comment: Ok is right. God bless you. Was a precious help!
Thank you very much...

Comment: Take a look here as I just recently upgraded mine: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/BikeNow/blob/lollipop/BikeNow/Fragments/ProntoMapFragment.cs

Comment: Hi James. Thank you very much. I appreciated very much

Answer (score 17):

Your map fragment class must implement `OnMapReadyCallback` and override `onMapReady()`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
    this.map = map;
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

In your `onCreateView` use `getMapAsync()` to set the callback on the fragment:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map); mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

All that you need to implement the google maps V2 is here: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Answer (score 4):

This might be late reply to your question, but may helpful to somebody else with the same issue.
GetMapAsync() expects implementation of callback object of type IOnMapReadyCallback.

Find more detail here in my blog entry: http://appliedcodelog.com/2015/08/androidgmsmapsmapfragmentmap-is.html

```
    //OnMapReadyClass
public class OnMapReadyClass :Java.Lang.Object,IOnMapReadyCallback
    { 
  public GoogleMap Map { get; private set; }
  public event Action<GoogleMap> MapReadyAction;

  public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
     {
        Map = googleMap; 

        if ( MapReadyAction != null )
           MapReadyAction (Map);
     }
    }
```

Now Call the GetMapAsync() and event Action return map instance on successful Map initialization.

```
    //MyActivityClass.cs 
GoogleMap map;
bool SetUpGoogleMap()
   {
     if(null != map ) return false;

     var frag = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<mapfragment>(Resource.Id.map);
     var mapReadyCallback = new OnMapReadyClass();

     mapReadyCallback.MapReadyAction += delegate(GoogleMap googleMap )
       {
        map=googleMap; 
       };

     frag.GetMapAsync(mapReadyCallback); 
     return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see this:

```
public class MapActivity : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
{

 public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
 {
        if (googleMap != null)
        {
           //Map is ready for use
        }
    }
  }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't think you need to test for null
[Docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync%28com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback%29);
At least is what I understood for it. But I don't know if the same can be said about Xamarin, I'm just a beginner and just stumbled in your answer and in the docs at the same time.

Comment: Hello, please see here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/
This is official Xamarin doc. You must check null.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use a view instead of a map fragment here is the implementation I applied to get this transition from a project that used a previous play-services version. Updated to 9.6.0 to comply with new FCM and caused issues in our map fragments.

```
private MapView mapView;

private GoogleMap mMap;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    // inflate and return the layout
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapFragment, container, false);

    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
{
    mMap = map;

}
```

And in your fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/Sismos"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Important to note the following permissions on your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

I was able to achieve this setup with out any errors on API 23 and the following libs on my Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your MapViewActivity class must implement IOnMapReadyCallback.

Also make sure you have installed the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package from NuGet and specified the required permissions:
- Access to the Network State – The Maps API must be able to check if it can download the map tiles.
- Internet Access – Internet access is necessary to download the map tiles and communicate with the Google Play Servers for API access.
(check the offcial documentation: [Using the Google Maps API in your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api))

```
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views;

public class MapViewActivity : MvxActivity, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
       private GoogleMap _map;
       private MapFragment _mapFragment;

       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            _mapFragment = (MapFragment) FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);

            if (_mapFragment != null) return;

           //GoogleMap properties
            var mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
                .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
                .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
                .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

            var fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

            //MapFragment can be programmatically instantiated
            _mapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
            fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.activitiesmap, _mapFragment, "map");
            fragTx.Commit();

            //used to initialize the GoogleMap that is hosted by the fragment                        
            _mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);

            // remainder of code omitted
        }

        //will be invoked when it is possible for the app to interact with the GoogleMap object
         public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            _map = googleMap;
            // If you have a map do something with it
            if (_map != null) 
            {
                _map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
                _map.MoveCamera (cameraUpdate);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### this definitly work in NAVIGATION_DRAWER ACTIVITY WITH FRAGMENT MAP

Run your prorramm by adding this in Top

```
 SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
```

**ADD THIS in ON CREATE METDOD()**

```
supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(); 

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.maplayout, new` `MapFragmentClass()).commit();`
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager sfm = getSupportFragmentManager();

sfm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map,supportMapFragment).commit();
```

**this will work chick it**