# How do you call GetMapAsync in xamarin without blocking the main thread?

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm trying to implement a fragment which implements a google map and shows a marker on it.

The fragment currently has two children, one button and one fragment with the attribute

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

When my viewpager switches to that (or a close by) fragment, the ui freezes for a bit

What I do currently is in the OnCreateView method of the fragment I call :

```
            MapFragment map_fragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.maps_map);
        map_fragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

and then I made the fragment implement the IOnMapReadyCallback interface where I do all my work

I tried creating an AsyncTask and have the GetMapAsync method to run in its DoInBackground but I get an error that GetMapAsync must be run on the main thread

Is there a way to avoid the freezing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the documentation [Add a map to an Android app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_a_map_to_an_android_app).

Here you can check how to add a [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) object to a [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that will handle the map, how to implement the [`OnMapReadyCallback`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) interface and use the [`onMapReady(GoogleMap)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)) callback method to get a handle to the [`GoogleMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html), and how to call/use the [`getMapAsync()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) on the fragment to register the callback.

For more details and sample code, visit the link that I provide in the documentaion.

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172897/use-getmapasync-instead-getmap-method-with-google-play-services-xamarin?rq=1) if it can help you and to know more information.